# Connect to Database between two computers without internet

Tags: database, sql-server

I want to connect my database on another computer without internet with a LAN cable, I've tried connected 2 machines with a LAN cable but it didn't work with database. My application works offline. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

**You need to, manualy, setup your Network adapter IP properties.**

Repeat the next steps on both devices:

1. Open *Control Panel*
2. Find and open, *Network Connections*
3. Right click on your network adapter and choose *Properties*
4. Click on *Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* item and click *Properties*
5. Inside *Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties* form select *Use the following IP address:* and populate that form like this:

PC1: IP address: 192.168.1.1 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.252 - click OK

PC2: IP address: 192.168.1.2 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.252 - click OK

The rest of the input boxes on this form can stay empty.

[image]

Comment: I've tried the same method with yours, but there is no result, can you show me the further steps?

Comment: Might also need a crossover cable rather than the standard cable (not all adapters can detect/adapt automatically)

Comment: After those steps,are you able to ping PC2 from PC1 and/or vice versa? If your answer is no, then you need a crossover cable as @Smock stated in his comment above. If your answer is yes, then try to elaborate more on your setup, consider editing your [question](https://superuser.com/posts/1515535/edit)

Comment: Make sure File and Print sharing and Network Discovery are both ON on both computers. You may need to set up the target user name and password of the source computer and share the database on the target machine to source user name. Make sure passwords are being used